# Ubuntu Studio automounts NTFS partition - how to disable?

Tags: mount, ntfs, 22.04, automount, ubuntu-studio

I have installed [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/), Version 22.04 LTS. I have also a NTFS partition at the same disk, which contains previously installed Windows OS.
Ubuntu Studio seems to automatically mount the NTFS partition at every computer startup (unlike normal Ubuntu).

**Where can I disable automounting of the NTFS partition at every computer startup?**

I would expect the automount to take place in `/etc/fstab`, but it is not there (I replaced parts of the UUIDs with `x`).

`cat /etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=664A-xxxx                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=6b1fe799-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /              ext4    defaults,discard 0 1
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
UUID=6af10a10-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx none           swap    sw              0       0
```

The automounted partition is `/dev/sda3` and it gets mounted under `/media/user/WIN10`. There is also another NTFS partition `/dev/sda4` at the disk (500MB), but it has got flags `hidden,diag` and it does not get automounted (just for explanation).

My `blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFIBOOT" LABEL="EFIBOOT" UUID="664A-xxxx" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="98cb88bd-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c96cdcf0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="WIN10" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="F60xxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="84569d75-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
/dev/sda4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="981xxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5c62d1c5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="6b1fe799-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7ed7d9b3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
/dev/sda6: UUID="6af10a10-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d74bac71-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

`mount | grep sda` output:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda3 on /media/user/WIN10 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

`dmesg | grep -i mount`:

```
[    0.122566] Mount-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.122566] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    5.411235] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    5.755437] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    5.757201] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    5.757925] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.758788] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    5.759805] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    5.773131] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    5.779286] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    5.779562] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    5.780677] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    5.780872] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    5.782590] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: discard. Quota mode: none.
[    5.786367] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    5.787998] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    5.789074] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[    5.799944] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    5.800204] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
```

`dmesg | grep sda`:

```
[    1.809792] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    1.809809] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.809822] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.809884] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.818988]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7
[    1.830314] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[    1.830318] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    5.411235] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    5.782590] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: discard. Quota mode: none.
[    6.872724] Adding 4002812k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4002812k SSFS
```

`dmesg | grep -i ntfs`:

```
[   62.029982] ntfs3: Max link count 4000
[   62.029991] ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
[   62.029992] ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
[   62.033266] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
```

Comment: Take a look at `System Settings` > `Removable Storage` > `Removable Devices`, anything helpful there?

Comment: Yes, this it it, thank you! Do you know how can I achieve this from command line or by editing some configuration files? I tried to grep all files in /etc/ for "mount" and "ntfs" and no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automounting can be configured in `System Settings` > `Removable Storage` > `Removable Devices`:

[image]

The config file is `~/.config/kded_device_automounterrc`, you could edit this file manually, but this changes only the file but does not apply the new settings.

Comment: You are right, editing the file does not apply the settings. But stil this is the solution that works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the partition to `/etc/fstab` with the `noauto` option. So the fstab entry should look like:

```
UUID=<UUID of Windows partition here>        /media/user/WIN10       ntfs      noauto
```

Replace `<UUID of Windows partition here>` with the necessary value - you can find the UUID by running `lsblk` to determine the device name that corresponds to your Windows partition, then run `blkid` to find the UUID associated with that device name. (Note that you want the UUID, **not** the PART_UUID.)

Comment: It seems promising, but unfortunately it doesn't work at all. Even if I use 'UUID=F60xxxxxxxxxxxxx' instead of '/dev/sda3'.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer, but as I have already commented - it does not work. I am using UUID, not the PART_UUID, I know about it.